# Is a perhaps somewhat cervellotic but not HARD question, regarding mathematical logic, suitable for MO?

Tags: support

This is the question:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/917492/can-the-logical-equivalence-of-two-different-statements-to-the-same-proposition

Comment: No, it's not suitable.

Comment: For anyone wondering: 'cervellotic' did not appear directly in the online English dictionaries I looked at, but it seems to be extracted from Italian and means 'weird' or 'odd' or 'strange'.

Comment: @ToddTrimble: So it doesn’t derive from cervesia as I assumed? That’s a shame.

Comment: related to the cervix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, questions / "puzzles" where you already know the answer are not suitable for MO. Also, it is usually not welcomed to immediately cross-post questions from other sites here -- thus even if a question asked on MSE would be suitable for MO as well, one should wait at least, say, a week or two whether the question gets satisfactory answers already on MSE. 
Regarding your particular question, I don't think it would be suitable for MO.

Comment: Alright, sorry for rushing! Thanks!